# fsck /dev/sd5 won't solve my problem

Tags: boot

As shown on the screenshot I can tell you that my disk problem is not solved. Can someone help me please?
https://ibb.co/HD8jzJD

Comment: Why do you think that fsck didn't work ?

Comment: because laptop won't start when selecting ubuntu :(

Comment: You've shown us a successful fsck of /dev/sda5 but not the reason why your boot dropped to (initramfs) prompt. Please show more of what led up to this.

Comment: I have Windows and Ubuntu on the same laptop. I wanted to resize the partitions so I did unmount the partition with Ubuntu on from a live usb stick. I guess there it went wrong when trying to boot again from hard disk...